# go install: no install location for directory

Tags: go

I think I know what's going on. The `GOPATH` changes when I installed [gvm](https://github.com/moovweb/gvm):

```
> alex@alex-K43U:~/go/src/m2k$ go install go install: no install
> location for directory /home/alex/go/src/m2k outside GOPATH
>
> alex@alex-K43U:~/go/src/m2k$ go env 
> GOPATH="/home/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4/global"
> GOROOT="/home/alex/.gvm/gos/go1.4"
```

What should I do know? I'm afraid that bringing the `GOPATH` to my workplace will mess up `gvm`. On the other hand, `go install` isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a package set, which is for all intents an encapsulated $GOPATH environment instance.

In short, use whatever name you like; "test_pkgset" is just an example name:

```
gvm pkgset create test_pkgset
gvm pkgenv test_pkgset // Launches whatever $EDITOR defaults to
```

Change the end of `export GOPATH; GOPATH=...` and `export PATH; PATH=...` lines to include $HOME/go:

```
export GOPATH; GOPATH="/home/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4/test_pkgset:$HOME/go:$GOPATH"
export PATH; PATH="/home/alex/.gvm/pkgsets/go1.4/test_pkgset/bin:${GVM_OVERLAY_PREFIX}/bin:$HOME/go/bin:${PATH}"
```

Finally, use it:

```
gvm pkgset use test_pkgset
```

Comment: gvm pkgset use test_pkgset did it for me